# How can I preselect Caps lock for a specific textField?

Tags: swift, keyboard, uikeyboard

When I begin to type, I want CapsLock to be preselected on the keyboard so I just type everything in Caps lock.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/autocapitalizationType)

> The UITextInputTraits protocol defines features associated with keyboard input to a text object. For a custom text object to support keyboard input, it must adopt this protocol to interact properly with the text input management system. The UITextField and UITextView classes automatically support this protocol.

The auto-capitalization behavior of a text-based view. Used with the autocapitalizationType property.

```
enum UITextAutocapitalizationType : Int {
case None
case Words
case Sentences
case AllCharacters
}
```

You can achieve auto capitalisation of all characters by:

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
```

Comment: So this doesn't technically select the 'Caps Lock' rather it Autocapitalizes everything in the textField

Comment: @Honey It highlights caps lock key on the `UIKeyboard`, technically selected state, and autocapitalises the text.

Comment: @Khundragpan I just tried this and it's not highlighting the selected state for me but it is capitalizing the text; weird?

Comment: Completely broken in AppleTV, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you want letters always capital on the textField, even if the user switches the Caps Lock button on the keyboard, you can use UITextFieldDelegate's `textFieldDidChange` method and set the text to be always uppercased, like this:

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
      textField.text = textField.text?.uppercased()
 }
```